# How to solve a formula from a mysql database field in php?

Tags: php, mysql

In my frontend I have someone who can change a formula in a form field.

The formula will be saved in a mysql database (text field right now).

For example this: "4 + (5 + 2 ) ^ (6 * 10)".

Now I want to solve this in my php code. My Problem is there I need the function
"pow" for example.

Is there any good solution to handle all or most math functions for php. Or do I have to manipulate the "^" to pow(4 + (5 + 2), (6 * 10)).

Comment: Unclear what you're asking because it's not clear what's "most math functions".

Comment: [Dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3664017/5267751)?

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two solutions: either use the [eval](http://php.net/eval) function which I don't recommend for security reasons (easiest way to achieve your goal), or use any expression library (like [Symfony's Expression Language](https://github.com/symfony/expression-language)).

While the former would be the fastest way, I would recommend the latter. There's a lot of flexibility you can achieve by exposing functions you only need or writing custom ones.

Comment: PHP's function token_get_all() allows you to get some security going for the eval function and only allow T_OPEN_TAG T,_LNUMBER, T_WHITESPACE and T_CLOSE_TAG as valid token_names... demo with safe code http://rextester.com/FMGQ6654 .. demo with "unsafe" code because trying to set a variable http://rextester.com/YALT96831